# JS Sorting an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following array:

```
var events = [
 {id : 1, start : 100, end : 120},
 {id : 2, start : 60, end : 240},
 {id : 3, start : 700, end : 720}
];
```

How do I sort based on `start` index while preserving the `id` something like:

```
var events = [
 {id : 2, start : 60, end : 240},
 {id : 1, start : 100, end : 120},
 {id : 3, start : 700, end : 720}
];
```

I tried:

```
events.sort()
events.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
```

But neither worked :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `array.sort(..)` function passes two elements of the array (which are being compared) to the comparator function you specify. Since, in that case, `a` and `b` are objects like `{id : 3, start : 700, end : 720}`, they can not be really compared like `a-b`.

Use this instead:

```
events.sort(function(a,b){return a.start - b.start;});
```